# How to specify local file system in HDFS API?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I want to get access to a local file system via HDFS API. I have the following:

```
String filename;
//...
Path p = new Path(filename);
p.getFileSystem(new Configuration()).create(p);
```

The issue is I have HDFS node on the same machine and when I call `p.getFileSystem(new Configuration()).create(p);` it tries to create a HDFS file, not a local file. Is there a way to access a ***local*** filesystem via `p.getFileSystem(new Configuration()).create(p)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File name has to be fully qualified with `file://`

```
    String filePath="file:///tmp/test.txt";
    public  void createFile(String path,Configuration conf) throws IOException {
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(path), conf);
        fs.create(new Path(path));
        fs.close();
     }
```

Works for S3, HDFS and Local